# Adding a confirmation checkbox to a form in Rails not tied to some attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Noob question! :)

I have a form, that has basically no point other than call `some_action`. The reason I use a form for this, is because we have a specific styling for this in our large website.

```
<%= styled_form_for(@user, :url => some_action_user_path @user)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.save_button %>
<% end %>
```

I thought, since it's a form, I should be able to put a checkbox in there. It should have no other goal than confirming the user wants to do this action indeed. E.g. "Yes, I want to do `some_action` to the user model".

How would I make a checkbox that does not really change any attribute or affect anything - Other than that it should be checked for the form to submit?

This is probably dead simple, but according to the documentation and various error messages I should provide arguments such an attribute (which I don't want...)

Comment: what does happen when user clicks on save button? Does it do any Ajax call or redirect user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` is meant to work on attributes of a model, which is what all the documentation you are reading is telling you. So if your model had a boolean column you could easily attach a check box to it.

If you ever want a form (or specific tag) that does not follow this, you can use the `_tag` version of these methods. For example, [form_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) or, in your particular case, [check_box_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag).

Example:

```
<%= styled_form_for(@user, :url => some_action_user_path @user)) do |f| %>
  <%= check_box_tag "do_some_method" %>
  <%= f.save_button %>
<% end %>
```

NOTE: You will only get a param entry for `:do_some_method` if it is checked off. If you want to get a param regardless, you have to add a `hidden_field_tag` before it.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "do_some_method", "no_dont_do_it" %>
<%= check_box_tag "do_some_method", "yes_do_it" %>
```

Now if the checkbox is selected you'll get `params[:do_some_method]` set to `"yes_do_it"`; if it's not checked off, instead of getting no entry, you'll get `params[:do_some_method]` set to `"no_dont_do_it"`.

Comment: I never came across '_tag' versions before - it's exactly what I needed. Thanks!